# как сделать так, что бы при нажатии кнопки, менялся размер контейнера?

Tags: c#, winforms

у меня есть контейнер, на нем кнопка. как сделать так, что бы при нажатии на эту кнопку размер контейнера становился например (высота 800, ширина 800). и что бы если я обратно нажму на эту кнопку, размер становился (высота 500, ширина 500)? можете пожалуйста написать сразу код для этой кнопки. буду очень благодарен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно экспериментировать так

```
  if (Form1.Size.Width >= 800 && Form1.Size.Height >= 800) 
    {
        Form1.Size = new Size(500, 500);
    } else 
    {
        Form1.Size = new Size(800, 800);
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! все сработало) очень благодарен

Comment: Пометить не забудьте как правильный

Comment: может вы мне поможете еще с одним вопросом разобраться? если сможете .https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1131509/389976